# UWP XAML: Is it possible to use XAML Behaviors to change what the selected item in a ListBox looks like?

Tags: xaml, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

If I define a ListBox in XAML and an associated DataTemplate inside of the ListBox.ItemTemplate, is it possible to use [XAML Behaviors](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors) to change how the selected item looks?

E.g. if I want the individual list box items to be represented by a blue Ellipse when they are not selected but want the selected item to be represented by a red Ellipse, can I use XAML behaviors to change how it looks at runtime based on the user changing the selection?

Comment: For this you'd need to restyle the ListBox's ItemContainerStyle and edit the Selected VisualStates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to style a custom [Style Template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299133.aspx) for (in your instance) the `Selected` VisualState that the `VisualStateManager` will invoke for that state wherein yes you can display a different look based on that state including an ellipse in the DOM.

Comment: I knew I could use that, I was just curious if it could also be done with XAML behaviors. I assume the answer is "no."

Comment: @AuthInfant ya there's just too many parts inside the templates you'd be working with to make that a good option. Editing the template would be the way to go, cheers!